# I'd like a query to update a column based on the value of two other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error. I have this so far:

```
update table
set valueA = 'True'
where valueB = 'y' AND valueC = 'n'
```

Comment: What's the error? and what data type is valueA?  (bit?) if so then use 1 for true 0 for false, not the string true.  or just remove the tic's  `True` or `false` but not as a string `'TRUE'`...

Comment: I stand corrected: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx string work fine.. @whytheq seems to be on the right path. The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
update x
set valueA = 'True'
from table x
where x.valueB = 'y' AND x.valueC = 'n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of these assuming bit datatype for valueA

```
update table
set valueA = True
where valueB = 'y' AND valueC = 'n'
```

OR

```
update table
set valueA = 1
where valueB = 'y' AND valueC = 'n'
```

Comment: thank you! not sure how this is any different but it seemed to work :s

Comment: The difference is in the quotes surrounding the `True` word.